# Determination of a constant based on continuity

Tags: continuity

The following defines function with a constant $b$ to be determined by using the continuity of a function:
    $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \dfrac{x-b}{b+1}, \quad x<0\\[1.75ex]
  x^2+b, \quad x>0
 \end{cases}$$

In short, for what value of $b$ is $f(x)$ continuous for every $x$.

What I did was to determine the right hand and left hand limit at zero to find that $b=0$ or $b=-2$ but I find this weird.

Comment: What's weird about that?

Comment: @dfeuer Well what actually occurs at $x=0$?

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh I think I got it @dfeuer, is it because the domain is defined as $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we require continuity we have

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=b=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\frac{-b}{b+1}$$
Can you solve this equation to find the value of $b$?

Comment: Yeah I did and got $0$ and $-2$.

Comment: Yes so there's two solutions.

Comment: So what happens at $x=0$?

Comment: At $x=0$ in the case of continuity we have $f(0)=\lim _{x\to0}f(x)$.

Comment: But $0\notin \mathbb{D}_f$?

Comment: You should understand that the function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^*$ for all $b$ but the question is to find $b$ such that the function $f$ is continuous at $0$ so it will be defined at $0$ and its value is $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$.